# Is there a way to specify default reviewers in Arcanist?

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

I use Arcanist and Phabricator at work and constantly have to manually specify the reviewer field whenever I do `arc diff`. 95% of the time I use the same reviewer value, which is my current team. I wonder if there's a config somewhere to pre-fill this value such that I do not have to manually fill it up every time I do `arc diff`?

I read about the `--reviewers` flag but for some reason it does not work for me. Doing:

```
$ arc diff --reviewers john.doe
```

I get:

```
<<Commit message>>

Summary:

Test Plan:

Reviewers:

Subscribers:
```

The reviewers field does not get filled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an alias?

`alias newdiff="arc diff --reviewers bob"`

Comment: The `--reviewers` flag does not work for me. I have ensured that I updated arcanist to the latest version.

Comment: touch test.php

git add -A

git commit

arc diff --reviewers username

Comment: what do you get in the next screen after you do `arc diff --reviewers bob`? might be an error in my installation >_<

Comment: an empty template with `Reviewers: bob`

Comment: Hi Chad, I would like to know if there is a way to define "view-policy" while creating the differential? 

Currently I am having to go to web application and manually set view policy for every differential revision, which is something that could go out of hand for our team of over 50 engineers.

Answer (score 0):

just execute a command

```
arc diff --reviewers 'brijace, john'
```